# Can the map or list be created using below yml entries

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

```
            a:
              b:
                controllers:
                  - Controller1:
                      put:
                      method1:
                        entitlements:
                          - ab: ORDER
                            cd: BYPASS_PROMOTION_RESTRICTIONS
                            de:  true
                  - Controller2:
                      post:
                        method2:
                          entitlements:
                            - ab: ORDER
                              cd: BYPASS_PROMOTION_RESTRICTIONS
                              de:  true
                  - Controller3:
                      get:  
                      method3:
                        entitlements: 
                          - ab: ANONYMOUS
                            cd: ANONYMOUS
                            de: true
```

Need help in understading how this can be added to a map and a list in a java class using configuration properties.

Comment: did you try using snakeyaml library?

Comment: nopes i dont hae idea of that..let me check or if you have something please share

Comment: You should describe what you want to do better. Based on the current text, it is very unclear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to know a possible Java root type for this YAML document? Do you want to know how to load the YAML? Do you want to transform the YAML document into flattened configuration values?

Comment: Its just a simple question.how can i use this yaml to create a list inside a list . let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: That question just does not describe what you really want to do. You can create a list inside a list without any YAML. There is no list inside a list in the YAML structure. Therefore it is very unclear what your YAML has to do with *list-inside-a-list*. Answering my questions from my previous comment would make it clearer what you want to achieve.

Comment: Well don't you see that there exist a list of controllers named controller1, 2 and so on and similarly these controllers contain a list with name as entitlement.